# HTML form checking in JavaScript using arrays

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use JavaScript to 'mark' a gap fill task that students of English could use. The students will input their answers in an HTML form in text input fields and if the answer is correct, a division to the left of the answer will display either a tick or a cross.  I'm using if statements to check the answers. I've managed to get it to work but only for the first input. It will not check multiple inputs.

This is the code I got to work for one input (but not multiple)

```
<form id='gapfill1' onsubmit="return checkAnswers()">

            <div id="gfillsentences">
            Please type in the correct preposition, choose from the list on the left:<br><br><br>

            As you walk <input type="text" name="prep1" required> this street, you can see:<div class="check" id="check1"></div><br><br>
            'Pret A Manger' is <input type="text" name="prep2" required> the entrance of 'The Arches Shopping Arcade'.<div class="check" id="check2"></div><br><br>
            The Italian Restaurant, 'L'ulivo', is <input type="text" name="prep3" required> 'Pret A Manger' and 'Herman Ze German'.<div class="check" id="check3"></div><br><br>
            There is a large clock <input type="text" name="prep4" required> the entrance to 'The Arches Shopping Arcade'.<div class="check" id="check4"></div><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="prep5" required> 'Pret A Manger', there is a pub called 'The Pricess of Wales'.<div class="check" id="check5"></div><br><br>
            There is a bin <input type="text" name="prep6" required> 'EAT'.<div class="check" id="check6"></div><br><br>
            There is an outdoor terrace <input type="text" name="prep7" required> 'Gordon's Wine Bar'.<div class="check" id="check7"></div><br><br>
            There is a Japanese Restaurant <input type="text" name="prep8" required> a public garden.<div class="check" id="check8"></div><br><br>
            There is a Shoe-Repair shop <input type="text" name="prep9" required> a 'Starbucks'.<div class="check" id="check9"></div><br><br>
            There is a Watersports Shop and a Mini Supermarket <input type="text" name="prep10" required> the railway bridge.<div class="check" id="check10"></div>
            </div>    
            <br><br><br><br>

            <div id="buttons">
                <input type="button" value="Check Answers" onclick="checkAnswers(gapfill1)"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
            </div>    

        </form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAnswers(form) {
        var prep1 = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep1"].value;
        var prep2 = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep2"].value;
        var prep3 = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep3"].value;
        var prep4 = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep4"].value;
        var prep5 = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep5"].value;
        var prep6 = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep6"].value;
        var prep7 = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep7"].value;
        var prep8 = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep8"].value;
        var prep9 = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep9"].value;
        var prep10 = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep10"].value;

        var check1 = document.getElementById("check1");
        var check2 = document.getElementById("check2");
        var check3 = document.getElementById("check3");
        var check4 = document.getElementById("check4");
        var check5 = document.getElementById("check5");
        var check6 = document.getElementById("check6");
        var check7 = document.getElementById("check7");
        var check8 = document.getElementById("check8");
        var check9 = document.getElementById("check9");
        var check10 = document.getElementById("check10");

        if (prep1 != "" && prep1 != null) {
            if(prep1 == "along") {
                check1.style.backgroundImage=
                    "url('file:///<file address>/tick.jpg')";
                return false;
                check1.focus;
            } else {
                check1.style.backgroundImage=
                    "url('file:///<file address>/cross.jpg')";
                return false;
                check1.focus;
            }
        } else {return false; check1.focus;}

        if (prep2 != "" && prep2 != null) {
            if(prep2 == "opposite") {
                check2.style.backgroundImage=
                    "url('file:///<file address>/tick.jpg')";
                return false;
                check2.focus;
            } else {
                check2.style.backgroundImage=
                    "url('file:///<file address>/cross.jpg')";
                return false;
                check2.focus;
            }
        } else {return false; check2.focus;}

        if (prep3 != "" && prep3 != null) {
            if(prep3 == "between") {
                check3.style.backgroundImage=
                    "url('file:///<file address>/tick.jpg')";
                return false;
                check3.focus;
            } else {
                check3.style.backgroundImage=
                    "url('file:///<file address>/cross.jpg')";
                return false;
                check3.focus;
            }
        } else {return false; check3.focus;}
    }

</script>
```

I'm trying to use arrays to hold the user input, correct answers and to grab each division to change the background picture:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function checkAnswers(form) {
        var answers = new Array(10);
        answers[0] = "along";
        answers[1] = "opposite";
        answers[2] = "between";
        answers[3] = "above";
        answers[4] = "to the left of";
        answers[5] = "in front of";
        answers[6] = "to the right of";
        answers[7] = "opposite";
        answers[8] = "next to";
        answers[9] = "under";

        var uInput = new Array(10);
        uInput[0] = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep1"].value;;
        uInput[1] = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep2"].value;
        uInput[2] = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep3"].value;
        uInput[3] = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep4"].value;
        uInput[4] = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep5"].value;
        uInput[5] = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep6"].value;
        uInput[6] = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep7"].value;
        uInput[7] = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep8"].value;
        uInput[8] = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep9"].value;
        uInput[9] = document.forms["gapfill1"]["prep10"].value;

        var marker = new Array(10);
        marker[0] = document.getElementById("check1");
        marker[1] = document.getElementById("check2");
        marker[2] = document.getElementById("check3");
        marker[3] = document.getElementById("check4");
        marker[4] = document.getElementById("check5");
        marker[5] = document.getElementById("check6");
        marker[6] = document.getElementById("check7");
        marker[7] = document.getElementById("check8");
        marker[8] = document.getElementById("check9");
        marker[9] = document.getElementById("check10");

        for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {   
            if (uInput[i] != "" && uInput[i] != null) {
                if (uInput[i] == answers[i]) {
                    marker[i].style.backgroundImage=
                        "url('file:///<file address>/tick.jpg')";
                    return false;
                    marker[i].focus;
                } else {
                    marker[i].style.backgroundImage=
                        "url('file:///<file address>/cross.jpg')";
                    return false;
                    marker[i].focus;
                }
            } else {return false; marker[i].focus;}
         }

    }
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong with either version (the second version is neater and requires less code)

Comment: As long as you do this with pure Javascript (that is, no server-side), your students can simply view the page source and get the right answers right away.

Comment: The very first `return` will **exit** the function.

Comment: @Nit This is not for a real website, more an exercise in Javascript. Clearly for a real website I wouldn't store the answers in the code for the site, although to be honest, I'd hope that the students wouldn't need to cheat its not very difficult.